# How to create managed objects and call managed methods in native C/C++ with embeded coreclr in .netcore?

Tags: .net, mono, .net-core

I have done that before on Mono and I think there should be some way to do the same with coreclr.

What I have done on Mono (compiled on VS2013 and runs on win10):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mono-2.0.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mono_set_dirs("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mono\\lib",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mono\\etc");

    MonoDomain *domain;
    domain = mono_jit_init(argv[0]);

    MonoAssembly *assembly;
    char* assemblyPath = "D:\\Mono\\hello.exe";
    assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, assemblyPath);
    if (!assembly)
        return 1;

    int returnValue = mono_jit_exec(domain, assembly, argc, argv);

    mono_jit_cleanup(domain);

    return returnValue;
}
```

The above code calls the entry method `Main()` in `hello.exe`. I can also load a type with `mono_class_from_name`, create a managed object with `mono_object_new`, initialize (call the constructor) it with `mono_runtime_object_init` and call methods on it with `mono_runtime_invoke`.

[Code on gist](https://gist.github.com/zwcloud/b342d264176ee2143aca970a9933e5cc)

All that is well documented on the [mono doc](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

I haven't digged into the [coreclr repo](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) and know nothing about the internal implementation.

I have already searched through the Internet and have found some possibly useful resources:

1. [How to call a .Net core library from native code on Linux?](http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/how-to-call-a-net-core-library-from-native-code-on-linux) on the .NET Foundation Forum
2. coreclr issues

   - [**#641** C++ Interop Documentation Request](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/641)
   - [**#1155** Question: mounting CoreCLR within a C++ app?](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1155)
3. Some coreclr host:

   - [official coreclr host](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/c637c919adcd0c0d7fcd8818810bcb727408fa51/src/coreclr/hosts)
   - [simpleCoreCLRHost](https://github.com/Marqin/simpleCoreCLRHost/blob/master/simpleCoreCLRHost.cpp)
   - [Fancy.CoreClrHost](https://github.com/fancyDevelopment/Fancy.CoreClrHost). Also here is [an article][http://www.fancy-development.net/hosting-net-core-clr-in-your-own-process] on this.

Add I have tried run dumpbin on the windows release of dotnetcore. The ouput show just a few functions are exported in coreclr.dll.

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      3    0 00018A30 GetCLRRuntimeHost
      4    1 00002030 GetMetaDataInternalInterface
      5    2 000021D0 GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic
      6    3 000021E0 GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal
      7    4 00001EA0 MetaDataGetDispenser
      8    5 00002EA0 coreclr_create_delegate
      9    6 00002FC0 coreclr_execute_assembly
     10    7 00002B80 coreclr_initialize
     11    8 00002DF0 coreclr_shutdown
      2    9 004D9E78 g_CLREngineMetrics
```

So I failed to find ways to do the same thing with coreclr in .netcore.

**My question is** how to do that on coreclr?

To be more concrete, are there any function in coreclr like `coreclr_class_from_name`, `coreclr_object_new`, `coreclr_runtime_object_init`, `coreclr_runtime_invoke` and so on? If there are, are they documented somewhere?

Comment: here's my example: https://github.com/Marqin/simpleCoreCLRHost

Comment: No, that's not I want. I have looked into your repo. See `3. Some coreclr host`. I have modified the question to clarify my problem.

Comment: It runs custom C# function, which you get via `coreclr_create_delegate` , and this is the only function we have in coreCLR, there is no `create_object`. BUT, I think you could be able to run `new()` method via it.

Comment: Just remember that `this` will be first parameter. Btw. my example does a little oposite - it runs C++ object method from C#.

Comment: I see. In your code, an `entry point` C/C++ method created by `coreclr_create_delegate` is called in managed code by using `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

Comment: That usage is so weird. :(

Comment: It's not if you look at it from C perspective. You just get function pointer from coreCLR (to any C# function you want) which you can run with custom argumets.